# Apple App review and server side database

Tags: iphone, server, versioning, review

This question might seem odd but it is an issue none the less.
I've always been in control of server side and client side when developing web applications. So when a new version is released, all is well and I upgrade both the client and the server. No that I'm in a scenario where there is 3rd party testers involved, specifically talking about iphone app reviewers, this causes some problems. How can the app reviewer test my app if the new app and the database is not compatible, all while 100's of users are currently using the app? Is the only answer to have versioned REST api on top of hacking business logic etc. etc. I would like to have clean, uncluttered code on server and client.
At one stage I built in version control inside my app, but apple did not like this and rejected the build, saying I'm not allowed to force users to update? huh?

Anyways, thanks for any advice!

Comment: I didn't know that about Apple not liking DIY version control. I've seen it in some big-brand apps and have done it in several of my own. It seems like a no-brainer to me - sometimes we needt to introduce breaking changes to our api's, and gracefully retire all our existing releases - and not just those that have 'auto update' switched on.

Comment: BTW I've battled with your main problem too - the only solution I can think of is using versioned api's, at least for the testing phase.

Comment: There is another solution - make the first thing your app does is visit a single-purpose api endpoint on your server, identifies itself, and you return the api URL for the rest of it's functionailty. This would allow you to point a production release in Apple review to your stage systems, and then subsequently point it your live systems when they're ready.

Comment: I don't think the API version check itself is what caused the rejection from Apple, but if they saw a message saying that you have to update (that is download a newer version from the App Store) during the review of the new  app release that is certainly a reason for rejection. If you are fully against API versioning, the new API version should be designed and implemented to be capable to function at least for some time next to the old API version, which will be discarded after the review is passed and the majority of users are updated automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments, I was also thinking of having a "test/staging" area for the apple testers, that makes my work a bit easier, and cleaner. Thanks a lot for reaffirming some of the ideas. PS. @A-Live, spot on, the tester got the update message and rejected the build.